# Using Angular 1.4 new router with components http throws a warning "Could not instantiate controller HeadlinesController"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, components, angular-routing

I'm new at this angular stuff. I'm trying to load a component with stuff I get from an http request. Right now When I try to run the code with HTTP request I get this warning.

> Could not instantiate controller HeadlinesController

Here's my headlines.js file

```
angular.module("RebelsApp.headlines", []).controller("HeadlinesController",  HeadlinesController);


function HeadlinesController() {

   $http.get('/dl/headlines')
    .success(function(dsp) {
    var title = "success";
     console.log(dsp); 
    })
.error(function (data, status) {
     var title = "fail";
    console.log(data); 
});   


}
```

I can't find any examples on using http request with the new router. Any help in the right direction would be nice. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the `$http` service in your controller

```
angular.module("RebelsApp.headlines", [])
    .controller("HeadlinesController", HeadlinesController);


function HeadlinesController($http) {

    $http.get('/dl/headlines')
      .success(function (dsp) {
        var title = "success";
        console.log(dsp);
    }).error(function (data, status) {
        var title = "fail";
        console.log(data);
    });

}
```

Comment: Yep, I knew I was just missing something small. Thanks buddy!